# How to rewrite common prefix as header?

Tags: shell

Say you're having a list of change notes like this:

```
2011-02-21: Removed first feature to get rid of previous customer
2011-02-21: Added second feature to open up new markets
2011-02-09: Implemented hot fix to calm down angry customer
2011-02-08: Developed project into a minimal viable product
2011-02-08: Started project
```

Can this be rewritten into the following format using standard shell tools?

```
2011-02-21
  * Removed first feature to get rid of previous customer
  * Added second feature to open up new markets

2011-02-09
  * Implemented hot fix to calm down angry customer

2011-02-08
  * Developed project into a minimal viable product
  * Started project
```

If so, how?

Comment: If it's homework, please tag it as so.

Comment: No homework, real work ... but before writing  something in Ruby I'd like to know if there's a simple shell solution for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pipe through this.

```
#!/bin/bash

lastprefix=""
while read prefix line
do
  if [ "$prefix" != "$lastprefix" ]
  then
    lastprefix="$prefix";
    echo ""
    echo "$prefix"
  fi
  echo "  *  $line"
done
```

Comment: That's a nice solution. I prefer it because it's very easy to understand and modify.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
awk -F: '$1 != prev {print $1; prev = $1} {$1 = ""; print "  *" $0}' inputfile
```

Comment: or even `{$1 = "  *"; print}`